# Templates and structures

Tags: structure

I have decided to use Structures as a section type for a section of our site. Can anyone point me to some good documentation for this?

In particular I have set up a structure and I have an `_entry.html` and an `index.html` file in a directory for the structure section. When I call the url `domain.com/mystructure` I am served a 404 error page instead of the `index.html` page.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't seen it already there is some good [Docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/sections-and-entries#section-types) on the Craft site on sections and how to use them.

Without seeing your Structure settings it is hard to pin-point exactly what the issue is here, but creating a Structure and adding your templates to it is a very easy procedure. I have attached a screenshot of a Structure for a project I am currently working on, so you can reference in case you have made a mistake somewhere.

[image]

So in my templates I have created a folder called `services`, and in there I have my `index.twig` and `_entry.twig` files. Try matching your Structure settings with the screenshot and see if that fixes your problems.